# Google Drive Insert Request in .NET library

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I am trying to use the sample code from https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples. In particular:

```
FilesResource.InsertRequest request = service.Files.Insert(body);
request.Upload(stream, mimeType);
```

It turned out that the `Upload` method doesn't exist in the FilesResource.InsertRequest class. I was reviewing and it just looks like the class is missing the method.

Maybe it is not implemented in the released .NET library?

Thanks.

Comment: Jason... thanks. Believe it or not: I didn't realize I was supposed to "accept" answers. I went back and accepted the answers that I found to be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately some recent changes to the .NET client library affected this part, I'll make sure the documentation is updated accordingly.

The library now supports the resumable upload mechanism but you have to use the InsertMediaUpload class instead:

```
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, mimeType);
request.Upload();
```

For a complete reference, please check the updated DrEdit.NET sample:

https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/browse/dotnet/DrEdit/Models/Utils.cs#290

Comment: Ok. That worked... however, it is compressing my images - I am uploading a png of +800kb and it gets uploaded as <100kb. Anyways: it works. It is too late for me today. Tomorrow I'll try to check the options to see if there is something to avoid compression. If I can't find it I guess I'll add another question. Thanks.

Comment: Check if you are setting the convert parameter and converting the image to the Google Docs format: convert

Comment: My code: `Dim request As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = service.Files.Insert(file, ms, "image/png") :
        request.Convert = False :
        request.Upload()`. File is the Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File class object, ms is a memory stream with the data. Doing that using a 800kb image gets compressed to less than 100kb. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: It would help if you could capture the HTTP request and response using Fiddler and share that log here

Comment: oh... this one was an error on my side. I was creating the memory stream using the wrong Bitmap format. Using the correct one it doesn't change the file. Thanks. Sorry about the confusion.